# How to pull out each character of string, and put in reverse order?

Tags: java, string, char, reverse

I'm building a program that reads a string consisting of 8 characters or less and writes it in reverse order, for example, apple would be changed to elppa.
This is what I have so far, Not sure where to go now, or if I'm even in the correct direction.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word, reverse;
    int lengthOfWord;
    char lc;//last character

    System.out.print("Enter word of 8 characters or less: ");
    word = in.nextLine();

    lengthOfWord = word.length();
    lc = word.charAt(lengthOfWord);
```

Comment: Please tag with relevant language (Java ?).

Answer (score 1):

How about trying like this:-

```
String reverseFunction(String s) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
   sb.append(s.charAt(i));
   return sb.toString();
 }
```